# Touch screen functionality not working on raspberry pi zero w and 5 inch lcd screen

Tags: pi-zero-w, touchscreen, lcd

I have a raspberry pi zero w  and a 5 inch lcd touch screen with hdmi.
I have the raspberry pi connected to the screen by HDMI. I am running the latest raspian OS on it.
It boots up and starts just fine.

The touch screen functionality is not working.
I have googled several solutions and tried many suggestions with no success.

I loaded the image and the driver that came with the display with no success for touch screen functionality. The display works fine and shows the desktop etc.

It uses the XPT2046 driver chip.i basically unzipped the image on the included DVD as well as updated the software and installed the driver from the DVD. I am using a raspberry pi zero w.

Anyone else ran into this issue? Any suggestions??
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to give details of what driver chip the LCD touch screen uses and what you've done on Raspbian to configure it. It's highly likely that a "bootable image" won't work with recent hardware like the 3B+ and 3A+ as it won't have the firmware & bootcode for those Raspberries.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It uses the XPT2046 driver chip.i basically unzipped the image on the included DVD as well as updated the software and installed the driver from the DVD. I am using a raspberry pi zero w. I am adding this information  to my question.